# PDO error on select?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I do the following in an (unsuccessful) attempt to grab a row from my MySQL database:

```
$qry = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT `post`,`user`,`id` FROM `posts` WHERE `id`='?' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$qry->execute(array($this->id));
$qry->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$this->row = $qry->fetch() or die(print_r($qry->errorInfo(), true));
```

(It's a function inside of a class, therefore the `$this` variable is used). So the error occurs at `$qry->fetch()` and the error message is:

`Array ( [0] => 00000 )`

What does this mean? And why isn't it working?

**ANSWER:** The `'` quotes around `WHERE id='?'` are unnecessary. It should be `WHERE id=?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the single quote around the parameter

```
`id` = ?
```

Comment: because you are making `?` as value and not as a parameter anymore.